# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop and it disappear when i clear the stored session data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have the following code :-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class Account extends React.Component {
  state = { user: {} };
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    axios
      .get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "user/self", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({ user: res.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("token")) {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h4> {this.state.user.name}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Account;
```

After login to the app i am storing a user token in session storage, then in account i am using the stored token to get the user info.
Every think fine for a while, then suddenly within a minutes after login, i got error :-

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
>   prevent an infinite loop.

The only way to make the error disappear is to clear the stored session token in the chrome browser .

please advice, what is wrong with my code.

Comment: This usually happens when you set state in `componentDidUpdate` unguarded/unchecked. Are you sure the error is from the component code shared?

Comment: i am not sure if this coming from this component, but it's the only component that using a componentDidUpdate and the only component use the stored token from session, which when i delete every thing return fine

Comment: Ah, where is the `componentDidUpdate` function? Can you update question with it?

Comment: @DrewReese i have fixed the issue by removing some lines, don't know why these lines caused the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional components run the entire function each render, so if the token exists you set state which causes a rerender... rinse and repeat.

Using an effect can help control this. It is akin to a lifecycle function of a class-based component. The following is an example of checking the token once when the component mounts.

```
const [isLoginned, setIsLoginned] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(isLoginned);

  if (sessionStorage.getItem("token")) {
    setIsLoginned(true);
  }
}, []); // <-- run effect once on component mount
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by removing the following line from App.js

```
const [isLoginned, setIsLoginned] = useState(false);
  console.log(isLoginned);
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("token")) {
    setIsLoginned(true);
  }
```

I am starter ReactJs developer not sure why this caused the issue .